# golang prepend a string to a slice ...interface{}

Tags: arrays, go, slice, prepend

I've a method that has as an argument `v ...interface{}`, I need to prepend this slice with a `string`. Here is the method:

```
func (l Log) Error(v ...interface{}) {
  l.Out.Println(append([]string{" ERROR "}, v...))
}
```

When I try with `append()` it doesn't work:

```
> append("some string", v)
first argument to append must be slice; have untyped string
> append([]string{"some string"}, v)
cannot use v (type []interface {}) as type string in append
```

What's the proper way to prepend in this case?

Comment: You should not have a method which takes `v ...interface{}` as an argument in the first place.

Comment: This guide may be useful for you. https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks

Comment: thanks for sharing @EzequielMoreno

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) can only append values of the type matching the element type of the slice:

```
func append(slice []Type, elems ...Type) []Type
```

So if you have the elements as `[]interface{}`, you have to wrap your initial `string` in a `[]interface{}` to be able to use `append()`:

```
s := "first"
rest := []interface{}{"second", 3}

all := append([]interface{}{s}, rest...)
fmt.Println(all)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/aLFNvj9S-z)):

```
[first second 3]
```

Comment: Ah thanks `append([]interface{}{s}, rest...)` worked for me